# UICollectionView reloadData But View Blinks

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have an `UICollectionView` and a custom `UICollectionViewCell` to display my content, which should be refreshed every second.

I am going to invoke `reloadData` method to reload the whole collection view to fit my needs.

But, but, My collection view cell blinks every time I reload data.

It seems like the image below. Two seconds of my app. The first second is OK. But second second, the collection view display reused cell first (yellow area) and then display the correct cell(configured cell) finally. Which looks like a blink.

[image]

It seems like a cell-reuse issue. `CollectionView` displays cells without completely finish configure it. How could I fix it?

My `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    YKDownloadAnimeCollectionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:[YKDownloadAnimeCollectionCell description] forIndexPath:indexPath];

    YKAnimeDownloadTask *animeDownloadTask = [[YKVideoDownloadTaskManager shared] animeDownloadTasks][indexPath.row];
    [cell setUpWithDownloadAnime:animeDownloadTask editing:self.vc.isEditing];
    cell.delegate = self;

    if (self.vc.isEditing) {
        CABasicAnimation *imageViewAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
        imageViewAnimation.fromValue = @(-M_PI/64);
        imageViewAnimation.toValue = @(M_PI/128);
        imageViewAnimation.duration = 0.1;
        imageViewAnimation.repeatCount = NSUIntegerMax;
        imageViewAnimation.autoreverses = YES;
        [cell.coverImageView.layer addAnimation:imageViewAnimation forKey:@"SpringboardShake"];

        CABasicAnimation *deleteBtnAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
        deleteBtnAnimation.fromValue = @(-M_PI/32);
        deleteBtnAnimation.toValue = @(M_PI/32);
        deleteBtnAnimation.duration = 0.1;
        deleteBtnAnimation.repeatCount = NSUIntegerMax;
        deleteBtnAnimation.autoreverses = YES;
        [cell.deleteBtn.layer addAnimation:deleteBtnAnimation forKey:@"SpringboardShake1"];
    } else {
        [cell.coverImageView.layer removeAllAnimations];
        [cell.deleteBtn.layer removeAllAnimations];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: are you using a custom cell with xib ?

Comment: @pawan All my code is in objective c

Comment: Does it still blink if you call `[collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath1, ...]]` instead of `reloadData`?

Comment: and why are you refreshing the collection view every second?

Comment: @neural5torm Yes, it still blinks.

Comment: @pawan Reload data to display my new data. The download percent for instance.

Comment: What if you set `[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO]` before your call to `reloadData`? (you might need to set it back to [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES] later in your code, after the reload/display cycle has ended).

Comment: @neural5torm Thanks. I have tested your code. Unfortunately, it does't work. I think it might be a cell-reuse issue. UICollectionView display the popped cell first and then configure it to correct one.

Answer (score 14):

Well I found the answer though it's been so long from the question.

Don't use `reloadData()` nor `reloadItems()`.

Use `collectionView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: yourSectionIndex))`. The animation will happen smoothly.

Comment: Hey! THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR THIS! :) You saved me from spending more time on my low-paying hourly rate side job. lol.

Comment: @GlennPosadas Glad it could help. Hope you get a better job.

Comment: Even this results in a blink :(

Comment: Yes it still blinks slightly

Answer (score 11):

```
self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: self.collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems)
```

Helped for me.

Comment: It still  blinks

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
    self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }, completion: nil)
}
```